# how to group corresponding values in 2 columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to group the table below (1) into result table (2)
These are sample values, in real they're corresponding numbers
and problem is to find out accounts on the right which pays to more 
then 1 account on the left. Been playing with Partition Over but not luck so far. 
I use SQL Server 2012,  thanks

```
(1)


       ACCOUNT1 | ACCOUNT2
        A1        |A2
        B1        |A2
        C1        |C2
        D1        |D2
        E1        |D2

(2)

  ACCOUNT | VALUES
    A2    | A1,B1
    C2    | C1  
    D2    | D1,E1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select account2, substring(list, 1, len(list)-1)
from (select distinct account2 from #t) t
cross apply (
    select account1 + ', ' as [text()]
    from #t
    where account2 = t.account2
    for xml path('')) x(list)
```